# Discord.js database using repl.it

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, discord, discord.js

I made a database script in repl.it and it's working but I keep getting null and then users database here is my code:

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("#مخالفات")) {
        var pfpMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;

        const violation = await db.get(`wallet_${message.mentions.members.first()}`);

        if (violation === null) violation = "العضو ليس لديه اي مخالفات";

        const pembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`شرطة لوس سانتوس`)
            .setDescription(`المخالفات المرورية :` + violation)
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setFooter("شرطة لوس سانتوس")
            .setThumbnail(pfpMember.user.displayAvatarURL());
        message.channel.send(pembed);
    }
});
```

And here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MQea.png

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Do you keep getting `null` from the database?

Comment: the problem is when i type #مخالفات to see my traffic ticket it gives the tickets that i have but with like nulltraffic light its keep tryping null before my tickets

Comment: Also you can't reassign `violation` because it is declared as `const`. Use `let` or `var` in this case.

Comment: i used and same

Comment: it gives me null  before the traffic light

Comment: like when i type #tickets the bot replies nullillegal speed

Comment: Could you `console.log(violation)` and show us what it prints out? And where is the violation saved to the database?

Comment: l gimme  a  moment

Comment: getting this 
```
null
[ 'مخالفات' ]
nullتجاوز السرعة القانونية
[ 'مخالفات', '<@738275876898078731>' ]
```

Comment: sry im typing the command in arabic cuz my discord server is arabic so ya

Comment: You're trying to fetch an object from the database. Try `db.get(\`wallet_${message.mentions.members.first().id}\`)` instead.

Comment: this error : Cannot read property 'id' of undefined @SkulaurunMrusal

Comment: That error means that it could not get the mentioned member, thus tried reading `.id` property of `undefined`, if we are talking about Tyler2P's suggestion. I think you should edit and improve your question with the info from comments.

Comment: You might find helpful taking a [tour here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Or reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also if the `null` comes from the database, it would be good to include how you write to the database.

Comment: Please provide more information as to where and how you define `db`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you cannot reassign `violation` as it is a constant, not a variable.

Using the following should solve the issue:

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("#مخالفات")) {
        var pfpMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;

        let violation = await db.get(`wallet_${message.mentions.members.first()}`);

        if (violation === null) violation = "العضو ليس لديه اي مخالفات";

        const pembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`شرطة لوس سانتوس`)
            .setDescription(`المخالفات المرورية :` + violation)
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setFooter("شرطة لوس سانتوس")
            .setThumbnail(pfpMember.user.displayAvatarURL());
        message.channel.send(pembed);
    }
});
```